# How to drag my dragging object in 'game'-unity?

Tags: unity, tower-defense

I have made a dragging sphere which drags, problem is how can I drag it using keyboard keys , I dont want to build it again on iphone simulator after experimenting with my code. for dragging it is not accepting mouse or any keyboard keys. Is it possible ?

Comment: If you want someone to answer this, then at the very least you're going to need to provide some of your source code.  The normal way to get movement input in Unity is with Input.GetAxis, but without seeing your code I don't know what you are doing or how to improve it.

Comment: Please provide some code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I did a quick search on unity forum and I found a great example
[Unity Drag an Object](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/18347-drag-an-object) without seeing your code though, I am not 100% sure what you want.